# BigCommerce PHP API not connecting

Tags: php, api, bigcommerce

I need an insight here in the PHP Code Connection with Bigcommerce, in this code it has an output "startupmiddlemiddle1" but it wasn't able to output the products.. Your help are highly appreciated.. Thanks!

```
<?php
echo "start";

require 'bigcommerce-api-php-master/bigcommerce.php';
use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce;

echo "up";

Bigcommerce::configure(array(
    'store_url' => 'https://store-h9a8oj.mybigcommerce.com/',
    'username' => 'admin',
    'api_key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    ));

echo "middle";
Bigcommerce::setCipher('RC4-SHA');
Bigcommerce::verifyPeer(false);
echo "middle1";

$products = Bigcommerce::getProducts();
foreach($products as $product) {
echo $product->name;
echo $product->price;
        }
echo "end";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is set up right.  Make sure you have all the requirements met (php 5.3+, cUrl extension enabled) and try it again.  Also make sure you copy all the files from the [github](https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php) into your bigcommerce-api-php-master/ directory, and not just the "bigcommerce.php" file.

Comment: i am using byethost free hosting, im sure it has php 5.3 but how do i know if it is curl extension enabled? and also, do i have to edit something on bigcommerce.php file? thanks so much josh!

Comment: Sorry I haven't logged in in a while.  For curl, you'll need to remove the semicolon from the curl extension in your php.ini (should look like ;extension=C:\php\ext\php_curl.dll) and you just remove the semicolon in front of it and restart your server.  You should not need to add anything to bigcommerce.php.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Cipher, You can use **rsa_rc4_128_sha** instead of **RC4-SHA**.

```
     // Bigcommerce::setCipher('RC4-SHA');
    Bigcommerce::setCipher('rsa_rc4_128_sha');
```

Hope it will work :)

Thanks and Regards,
Alpa W